Name of theory for group dynamics in improvisation?
I am interested in learning more about group dynamics in improvisation when playing music together (physically in realtime with or without audience). Is there some established theory and nomenclature for it. That could be used to learn and reason about and understand the behavior of, communication between and thoughts of participants for example.

I think you'll get the best answers by clarifying a bit more about what kinds of words you're looking for. Words like "collaboration," that are very broad and applicable to many non-musical contexts? Words that are closely tied to music or even specific genres like "groove" or "in the pocket"? As it stands, there's nothing in this question to indicate that it's about music at all, just about language and sociology/psychology.

Also note that the best questions are narrow, not broad; a question like "Tell me anything in general that you can think of around this topic" has a hard time picking a "best answer." I recommend, instead, "tell me the best way to talk about this specific concept."

I did not ask for the theory contents. I asked for the theory name. That is as narrow as I could make it. I object to your claim it is not about music. It is about playing music. I feel very underfed about what cues are used when playing together and want to read the theories of it.

Also your first comment makes no sense. It is impossible to ask about words you do not know. That would be like monkeys writing Shakespeare.

Why would it not be about music just because it is interdisciplinary?

I just mean, literally, there are no words in this question title or body that are clearly about music. The only thing that makes us interpret it that way is the site on which you posted. And it's not clear to me that you're looking for anything that wouldn't also be applicable to, say, an improv theatre class or even a debate team or something of the sort. In which case, a site like https://english.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit, or perhaps one focused on sociology (I don't see such a one among Stack Exchange).

My comments seem to have touched a nerve; I'm not trying to give you a hard time, but to understand your question and help produce answers that are useful to you.

I tried adding some extra content that it is music playing I am interested in.

Group improvisation in general is a very active area of music theory study. Searching for topics like "collective improvisation", "group improvisation", along with "dynamics" or related terms should give you a wealth of material to peruse. There isn't a special name for the field.
Many article discuss specific musicians or groups and their approach(es), and there are also numerous analyses of group-improvised pieces.
A recent article that might interest you is "one to one: Composing Social Dynamics" (Charlie Sdraulig, Perspectives of New Music Vol. 60 no. 2). In it, the author discusses his performance installation one to one in which one performer and one audience member interact with each other in creating not only an improvised musical experience, but also an intimate and dynamic social connection. Here's a brief excerpt:

My performance-installation one to one (2018 – 20) is a sequence of three compositions, each for one performer and one audience member (audient) at a time. Within these encounters, each develop connections characterized by intimacy, nuance, and quietude. For instance, in the title piece, violinist Marco Fusi aims to coordinate his soft bowing and breathing with the audient's respiratory cycles. However, the audient often spontaneously synchronizes or consciously alters their breath lengths as Fusi plays, which catalyzes further cycles of mutual adaptation.

This is not "group improvisation" in the sense of multiple, simultaneous instruments, but it does include insights that directly apply to collective performance.
There's also the book essay "Sync or Swarm: Musical Improvisation and the Complex Dynamics of Group Creativity" (David Borgo, in Algebra, Meaning, and Computation, Springer, 2006), which is frequently cited. A search on Google Scholar for source that cite "Sync or Swarm" included a 2024 article "Theorizing Musical Improvisation for Social Analysis (Ryan Martin, Music Theory Spectrum).
David Borgo has written a number of articles on the subject of group improvisation, including "Rivers of Consciousness: The Nonlinear Dynamics of Free Jazz."
